# Suma con condicional en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla que se llama productos, los productos se dan de alta con un sku único y en una columna llamada cantidad estan las existencias existencia, quiero sumar todos los registros que hay en la columna cantidad pero solo sume los del mismo sku, esta es mi tabla:

```
*----*---------*----------*----------*
| id |   sku   |  nombre  | cantidad |
*----*---------*----------*----------*
| 1  |  1001   | Refresco |    20    |
*----*---------*----------*----------*
| 2  |  1002   | Papas    |    100   |
*----*---------*----------*----------*
| 3  |  1003   | Tortillas|    15    |
*----*---------*----------*----------*
| 4  |  1001   | Refresco |    70    |
*----*---------*----------*----------*
| 5  |  1003   | Tortillas|    30    |
*----*---------*----------*----------*
| 6  |  1001   | Refresco |    20    |
*----*---------*----------*----------*
```

El código que estoy aplicando es:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(sku=1001, cantidad)) FROM productos;
```

Manda este error:

> error sintáctico cerca del elemento inesperado `if'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT sku, nombre, SUM(cantidad) as Total
FROM tabla
WHERE sku = 1001
GROUP BY sku, nombre;
```

Pudieras hacerlo así:

- Seleccionas las columnas deseadas `sku` y `nombre`
- Dentro de la función `SUM()` pasas a la columna `cantidad`
- Agrupas por `sku` y por `nombre`
- Filtras con `WHERE` donde `sku` = 1001

  - En este último punto pudieras aplicar mas filtros valiéndose del operador lógico `AND`

Si deseas que la suma se realicé por todos los productos agrupándolos por su `sku` entonces solo remueve el `WHERE` de tu consulta quedando así:

```
SELECT sku, nombre, SUM(cantidad) as Total
FROM tabla
GROUP BY sku, nombre;
```

Ahora con tu misma sintaxis creo que el cambio debería quedar así:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(sku=1001, cantidad, 0)) AS sku1001 FROM productos......;
```

> Pues tu sintaxis de `IF` esta incompleta, es decir tienes la parte de la comparación y cantidad si la comparación es cierta pero te falta agregar el valor si dicha evaluación resulta falsa.

Answer (score 3):

Para lo que deseas puedes seleccionar la suma del agrupamiento de datos por la columna que deseas, claro, condicionando por el codigo, ejemplo funcional;

```sql
SELECT sku, nombre, SUM(cantidad)
FROM productos
WHERE sku = 1001
GROUP BY sku, nombre;
```

Ejemplo practico de tus datos;
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74b870/2

> Extra

Puede que te surja la duda de como hacer lo mismo con varios `sku`, la solución es utilizar la clausula `IN`;

```sql
SELECT sku, nombre, SUM(cantidad) as Total
FROM productos
WHERE sku IN (1001,1003)
GROUP BY sku, nombre;
```